# Youtube embedding doesn't work in HTTPS site

Tags: feature-request, ssl, youtube

While using HTTPS site, all YouTube embedded videos turn into big blank spaces on the page as seen in the image below. Even if the source link is HTTPS, the parser turns it into HTTP for the embedding.

[image: See this video for live demonstration:]

If I edit the elements and replace HTTP with HTTPS within the embedded code, however, the video shows fine:

[image: See this video for live demonstration: [video]]

The embed code should match the protocol used to open the page.

Comment: For those (like me) who didn't even know this feature existed; it's an option that is enabled on some sites [like gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com). [HTTP example](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25126/hints-for-level-27-of-treasure-bay-on-fragger/25133#25133), [HTTPS example](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25126/hints-for-level-27-of-treasure-bay-on-fragger/25133#25133).

Comment: i cannot see the https example. i can only see the link but not the video

Comment: @Wandang which is the whole point of this post - to get the video visible too.